# How I can iterate through a bunch of documents and execute spacy's nlp for each of them, without getting a memory error?

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, spacy

I have 90 documents with around 40 pages each (raw text). I want to tokenize them with spacy.

```
nlp = spacy.load('de')
tokenized_list = []

for document in doc_collection:
    temp_doc = nlp(document)
    tokenized_list.append(temp_doc)
```

It's working for a low number of documents, but if i want to tokenize all, then it gives a "MemoryError".

```
"...site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 234, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)

MemoryError"
```

Does somebody know how I can fix it?

Update:
I can execute it over and over again without changing the documents and it get stuck sometimes in this document sometimes in that - really weird... Does somebody know a similar problem?

Comment: Try a comprehension instead? `tokenized_list = [nlp(doc) for doc in doc_collection]`

Comment: Try to monitor the used memory, 90 text documents with 40 pages doesn't seem big at all. Seems like the problem is rooting somewhere else

Comment: @Clusks Already tried, but still the same problem. But thanks anyway!

Comment: What is each item like in doc_collection? Is it a large amount of text? This may be of relevance to you https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1636

Comment: Try using `nlp.pipe`, which processes the texts as a stream and yields `Doc` objects: https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe

Comment: @InesMontani Thanks for your advice! Tried it this way: `for doc in nlp.pipe(doc_collection):` But it results in the same error in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from python 32-bit to 64-bit version. Now it's working! I tried a lot, but no other thing worked except this version change.